# Writing data to a public text file in Android

Tags: android

I need to write some data into a text file to be read from standard text editor applications. In my app (running on **Android 7.0**) compiled with `targetSdkVersion 27` I'm doing this trough this method, that works (or at least it seems to work since I got no exeptions):

```
private void storeLocation(Location location) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStreamWriter;

        outputStreamWriter = this.openFileOutput(logPath.getPath(), Context.MODE_APPEND);

        outputStreamWriter.write(("LAT: " + location.getLatitude() + "\n").getBytes());
        outputStreamWriter.write(("LON: " + location.getLongitude() + "\n").getBytes());
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Variable `logPath` is defined in this way in application `onCreate()` event handler:

```
File logPath = new File("VIPER_" + getCurrentDateTime() + "_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".log");
```

I tought to find this file inside application private data folder but it's not here (maybe it's deleted after application closing?).

If I try to specify a different folder (like public downloads folder etc.) I got all sort of exceptions like `file not found`, `read only filesystem`, `presence of / character in path` etc.

There's a (simple) way to allow an application without having to deal with a `FileProvider` implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found and that's working for some reason is the following:

```
logPath = new File( this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "VIPER_" + getCurrentDateTime() + "_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".txt");


private void storeLocation(Location location) {
    try {
        final FileOutputStream outputStreamWriter = new FileOutputStream( logPath, true);

        final SimpleDateFormat time_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.getDefault());

        final String line = time_format.format(
                new Date()) + String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                " %f %f %f %f\n",
                location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude(),
                location.getAltitude(),
                location.getBearing());

        outputStreamWriter.write(line.getBytes());

        outputStreamWriter.flush();
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I really haven't got why this code works while the previous wasn't ... maybe one of the reason is `openFileOutput()` call I was using in the first sample or maybe is the `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS` I'm using now. What's certain that even if now the file is availabe its availability is not immediate but may require a variable timespan (from some seconds to some minutes).
May this code be of any help to someonelse.